# error on drop down list (JS)

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add +10% to a value if that value is selected , but before i can implement it i need to make it work properly , first of the page shouldn't refresh and when i add a value and then i want to change it to another i want the old value from the other textbox to subtract ... i tried with a simple if/else if / else statement but because of the first error it won't work and i even ain't sure that it is working right. Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>lol</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <input type="text" id="hp">
        <input type="text" id="ea">
        <input type="text" id="ed">
        <input type="text" id="pa">
        <input type="text" id="pd">
        <input type="text" id="sp">

        <select>
            <option value="hp">HP</option>
            <option value="ea">EA</option>
            <option value="ed">ED</option>
            <option value="pa">PA</option>
            <option value="pd">PD</option>
            <option value="sp">SP</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" id="sub" onClick = "return at()">
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function at () {
            var a = document.form.select.options,
                i = document.form.select.selectedIndex,
                ea = Number(document.form.ea.value),
                ed = Number(document.form.ed.value),
                hp = Number(document.form.hp.value),
                pd = Number(document.form.pd.value),
                pa = Number(document.form.pa.value),
                sp = Number(document.form.sp.value),
                eaS,edS,pdS,paS,spS,hpS = 0;

            if(a[i].text === "hp"){
                hpS = hp*0.1;
            }else if(a[i].text === "ea"){
                eaS = ea*0.1
            }else if(a[i].text === "ed"){
                edS = ed*0.1
            }else if(a[i].text === "pa"){
                paS = pa*0.1
            }else if(a[i].text === "pd"){
                pdS = pd*0.1
            }else if(a[i].text === "sa"){
                spS = sp*0.1
            }

            document.form.ea.value = eaS;
            document.form.ed.value = edS;
            document.form.hp.value = hpS;
            document.form.pd.value = pdS;
            document.form.pa.value = paS;
            document.form.sp.value = spS;

            return false;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try changing document.form to document.forms[0] and you should be through

Comment: nope still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the JavaScript console

I am willing to bet it has the error that says something like. If you do not see the error, set up your console so it persists errors across page navigation.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'select' of undefined

You are looking for an element with the name of form and one with the name of select, but your form/select has no name.

```
<form action="">
<select>
```

should be

```
<form name="form" action="">
<select name="select">
```

Ideally you would drop the document.name.name syntax and use getElementById. Put an id on the select and form and reference the inputs that way too. Also a switch statement would be your friend.

Your code could be written without if statements, just use look ups based on the selects value.

```
function at() {
    var sel = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var val = sel.options[sel.options.selectedIndex].value;
    var input = document.getElementById(val);
    if (input) {
         var val = input.value;
         resetValues();
         input.value = parseFloat(val) * .1;   
    }
}

function resetValues() {
    var inputs = document.getElementById("myForm").getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++) {
        var inp = inputs[i];
        if (inp.type==="text") inp.value = 0;
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle - Running example](http://jsfiddle.net/3TAUA/)

Comment: Ok, but how can i make the value if it's changed not to 0 , but back to the previous value?

Comment: @aleksXPO I have no idea what you are asking there. If you do not want it reset to zero, than you do not call that function resetValues. And if you want a NaN to not appear, it is a simple if check.

Answer (score 0):

many changes needed :

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>lol</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <input type="text" name="hp" id="hp">
        <input type="text" name="ea" id="ea">
        <input type="text" name="ed" id="ed">
        <input type="text" name="pa" id="pa">
        <input type="text" name="pd" id="pd">
        <input type="text" name="sp" id="sp">

        <select id="mySelect">
            <option value="hp">HP</option>
            <option value="ea">EA</option>
            <option value="ed">ED</option>
            <option value="pa">PA</option>
            <option value="pd">PD</option>
            <option value="sp">SP</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" id="sub" value="Submit" onClick = "return at()">
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function at () {
            var a = document.getElementById('mySelect').options,
                i = document.getElementById('mySelect').selectedIndex,
                ea = Number(document.forms[0].ea.value),
                ed = Number(document.forms[0].ed.value),
                hp = Number(document.forms[0].hp.value),
                pd = Number(document.forms[0].pd.value),
                pa = Number(document.forms[0].pa.value),
                sp = Number(document.forms[0].sp.value),
                eaS,edS,pdS,paS,spS,hpS = 0;

            if(a[i].text === "HP"){
                hpS = hp*0.1;
            }
            if(a[i].text === "EA"){
                eaS = ea*0.1
            }
            if(a[i].text === "ED"){
                edS = ed*0.1
            }
            if(a[i].text === "PA"){
                paS = pa*0.1
            }
            if(a[i].text === "PD"){
                pdS = pd*0.1
            }
            if(a[i].text === "SA"){
                spS = sp*0.1
            }

            document.forms[0].ea.value = eaS;
            document.forms[0].ed.value = edS;
            document.forms[0].hp.value = hpS;
            document.forms[0].pd.value = pdS;
            document.forms[0].pa.value = paS;
            document.forms[0].sp.value = spS;

            return false;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
<form action="">
    <input type="text" id="hp">
    <input type="text" id="ea">
    <input type="text" id="ed">
    <input type="text" id="pa">
    <input type="text" id="pd">
    <input type="text" id="sp">
    <select name="select">
        <option value="hp">HP</option>
        <option value="ea">EA</option>
        <option value="ed">ED</option>
        <option value="pa">PA</option>
        <option value="pd">PD</option>
        <option value="sp">SP</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" id="sub" value="Submit">
</form>

var sub = document.getElementById("sub");

function at() {
    var a = document.forms[0].select.options,
        i = document.forms[0].select.selectedIndex,
        ea = Number(document.forms[0].ea.value),
        ed = Number(document.forms[0].ed.value),
        hp = Number(document.forms[0].hp.value),
        pd = Number(document.forms[0].pd.value),
        pa = Number(document.forms[0].pa.value),
        sp = Number(document.forms[0].sp.value),
        eaS, edS, pdS, paS, spS, hpS;

    eaS = edS = pdS = paS = spS = hpS = 0;

    if (a[i].text === "HP") {
        hpS = hp * 0.1;
    } else if (a[i].text === "EA") {
        eaS = ea * 0.1
    } else if (a[i].text === "ED") {
        edS = ed * 0.1
    } else if (a[i].text === "PA") {
        paS = pa * 0.1
    } else if (a[i].text === "PD") {
        pdS = pd * 0.1
    } else if (a[i].text === "SA") {
        spS = sp * 0.1
    }

    document.forms[0].ea.value = eaS;
    document.forms[0].ed.value = edS;
    document.forms[0].hp.value = hpS;
    document.forms[0].pd.value = pdS;
    document.forms[0].pa.value = paS;
    document.forms[0].sp.value = spS;

    return false;
}

sub.addEventListener("click", at, false);
```

ob [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/gDV7E/)

I have not fixed every problem that you may have with your code, just the main part.And you can use this fiddle to work through your other problems.

Comment: Ok, but how can i make the value if it's changed not to 0 , but back to the previous value?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean? Is this question part of the original that you asked?